# Is the empty set a collection of subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set and $\mathcal{C}$ any collection of subsets of $X$. Does this "definition" of $\mathcal{C}$ allows $\mathcal{C}=\emptyset$ or must $\mathcal{C}$ contain at least one element?

Comment: It may depend on context whether or not an empty collection is meaningful. It is common for authors to explicitly exclude the empty object from discussion as it would lead to some trivial case, but care must be taken. One could define "$C$ is a collection of subsets of $X$" to mean: $$C\subseteq\mathscr{P}(X)$$In which case $C=\emptyset$ is valid

Comment: @FShrike, I think you could post that as an answer so that this question would no longer appear unanswered.

Comment: @MarkS. ; ) Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may depend on context whether or not an empty collection is meaningful. It is common for authors to explicitly exclude the empty object from discussion as it would lead to some trivial case, but care must be taken.

One could define "$C$ is a collection of subsets of $X$" to mean:

$$C\subseteq\mathscr{P}(X)$$

In which case $C=\emptyset$ is valid. On the other hand, an author may wish to talk about elements of this collection, or take some union of it, some intersection, any operation at all really. If they're not clear, then in that case you either have to really carefully check that everything they're saying still works with $C=\emptyset$ (there are conventions for empty union and empty intersection) or you have to make a note to yourself that this discussion only pertains to nonempty collections.

I think I'm right in saying that forgetting about the empty set is a slightly notorious thing, and it is rarely addressed in proofs even at points where it is important. Watch out!